# I want to do setup for user but at initial stage i want to make dafault register and make a login api in nestjs project with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I want to do setup for user but at initial stage i want to make dafault register and make a login api in nestjs project with mongodb

I want to do setup for user but at initial stage i want to make dafault register and make a login api in nestjs project with mongodb.